# Beginner in C - Array of strings lost content after initialization in cyklus

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to make array of strings each representing one card of a poker deck from 2 strings (ranks, colors). If I try print card immidietly after assignment it's ok but if I try it after all assignments nothing happend.

My "code":

```
int main(void)
{
    char rank[] = "23456789TJQKA";
    char color[] = "cdhs";
    char deck[52][3];
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            deck[k][0] = rank[i];
            deck[k][1] = color[j];
            deck[k][2] = 0;
            k++;
            printf("%s\n",deck[k-1]);    // this print works
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n",deck[0]);    //this does nothing (even if I change index)


    //-------------------------- here I am trying make all possible pairs but deck is now empty :(

    k = 0;
    char allPairs[1327][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++) { //**edit** - thanks ;)
            allPairs[k][0] = deck[i][0];
            allPairs[k][1] = deck[i][1];
            allPairs[k][2] = deck[j][0];
            allPairs[k][3] = deck[j][1];
            allPairs[k][4] = 0;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

All seems to work now thanks guys!

Comment: The first section works in my test. The only problem was a lack of a newline whitespace before `printf("%s\n",deck[0]); //this does nothing (even if I change index)`

Comment: In the second section you comment `but deck is now empty`. How do you know that, since section 2 has no output?

Comment: Typo in `for (int j = 0; j < 3; i++)` ==> `for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)`.

Comment: Add a tag to each `printf()` so you can see what they are: `printf("Card: %s\n", deck[k-1]);`, for example, and `printf("TEST: %s\n, deck[0]);`. Then add a similar printout in the section where you're defining all the pairs. Now that you've corrected your `i` and `j` values, is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is replace `i++` with `j++` in the following statement

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; i++)
```

and also comment out the following line as it is printing `2c` again:

```
printf("%s\n",deck[0]);    //this does nothing (even if I change index)
```